# form's "valid" attribute or analog

Tags: css, forms, validation, submit

I need to make my submit button inactive (visually). Is there some features in HTML/CSS for that except ones, I already use and which work only in chrome?

```
form:invalid input[type="submit"]{
  background-color: grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
form:valid input[type="submit"]{
  background-color: green;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can easliy do it with html, by setting the attribute `disabled="disabled"`. You can use it in this context:

```
<form>
    <button id="submit-button" type="submit" disabled="disabled">submit</button>
    <input id="submit-button2" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="submit">
</form>
```

However, you can also do this with javascript.

```
document.getElementById('submit-button').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

You could then just use css attribute selectors to update the style of the button (works on most modern browsers):

```
button[disabled="disabled"] { 
    background-color: yellow;
}

input[disabled="disabled"] {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

[here's a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/0s8nabcu/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need only visual stuff, such as color, size etc.. It's already disabled by the 'required' attribute of inputs. I can make it via js, but if there is a more natural way(like 'form:invalid input') - i prefer it.

Comment: Ahh ok, I've updated my answer and the jsfiddle. Using the disabled="disabled" css attribute selector will give you access to style buttons that should be disabled. But by them having those attributes, html already styles them to be grayed out, so not 100% sure if you want to do something else?

Comment: thanks! And if the button disabled by not-checking 'required' inputs in form, can i anyway use button[disabled="disabled"] selector?I asking because it looks like my try with form:invalid input[type="submit"]

Comment: I've update m answer and jsfiddle. It depends if your validation uses disabled="disabled" attribute to disable your submit button, if that's the case, then yes you can. eg form:invalid input[disabled="disabled"] { ... }

Comment: Your  js advice worked fine. But  I still wondering what is the html/css state (how can i catch it) of  'submit' while some of  'required' inputs are empty...

Comment: Your code works fine for exactly that: `form:invalid input[type="submit"] {background-color: green;}`. Its supported by most modern browsers (Google ":invalid selector browser support"), and not just chrome. There's no other way except with JavaScript (adding and removing classes / attributes).